# NAT'ing a non-directly connected network

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

With the following UFW configuration added at the top of before.rules (besides all respective prerequisites such as enabling IP routing on the platform itself, changing default forward policy from DROP to ACCEPT and enabling IP forwarding in the UFW config):

```
*nat :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

does subnet 10.100.0.0/24 have to *directly* connect to any of the interfaces of the Ubuntu VM running that UFW? If so how do I configure UFW to NAT a non-directly connected one towards the Internet? E.g.:

```
UserA--10.100.0.x/24---10.100.0.1/24--(Router1)--1.1.1.1/24-----1.1.1.2/24--(UFW)--Internet
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UFW** is an interface for **netfilter** and it uses **iptables** for configuration.
It means that, when you try to edit configuration file, you are editing iptables rules. Therefore you can find help in [iptables manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables).

Every iptables rule does two things:

1. matches the IP packet
2. executes action on the packet

In the case of the rule you are wondering about, it will match any packet that was already routed to be send out of interface `ens3`, and has source IP in 10.100.0.0/24 network. Once matched it will be NATed to IP address of the `ens3` interface.

### FORWARDING - no UFW

I suspect you have made assumption when asking your question and you didn't say what is actual problem you are trying to solve. It sounds like you are unable to forward network 10.100.0.0/24 to internet. The question feels like [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)
If you are routing traffic through the Linux, you must enable ip forwarding.
To verify if forwarding is enabled run:

```
echo /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You will get return `0` for `disabled` and `1` for `enabled`.

When **not** using **UFW** you can enable it permanently by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Above command will append the text in the quotes into the mentioned file.
In order to apply the new setting run:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

### UFW

Although above setting will work with **UFW** it would be wise to stick to ufw base configuration.
Check the UFW configuration:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

You may see that the default `routed` policy is `disabled`:

```
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
```

Now edit `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`. Settings in this file will overwrite `/etc/sysctl.conf`
In the above file locate line `#net/ipv4/ip_forward=1` and remove the `#`.
Save the file and reload the ufw:

```
sudo ufw reload
```

When displaying verbose status this time, you should see default routed policy changed from `disabled` to `deny`.

To allow routing run:

```
sudo ufw default allow routed
```

This commend will modify `/etc/default/ufw` line, from

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"
```

to

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

### MASQUERADE

With above settings, your rules in `/etc/ufw/before.rules` should work, but they need to be before `*filter`. It is also a good idea to flush the rules `-F` before appending new ones `-A`. Otherwise anytime the ufw service would be restarted, it would add another copy of the same rule.

```
*nat 
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-F
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

After applying these setting the ufw needs to be reloaded:

```
sudo ufw reload
```

The ufw status will not display the NAT configuration but it can be verified by checking `iptables` with:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L -v
```

and the `POSTROUTING` chain should look as below:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    ens3    10.100.0.0/24        anywhere
```

Remember that your firewall will also need to have a route back to your 10.100.0.0/24 network.

Comment: RomanK: Thanks for your reply, so my non-directly connected 10.100.0.x/24 should be translated too - but it's not, probably 'cos my nat table has no entries for some reason. I've already done all those preceding steps like enabling the routing etc (referring to them as prerequisites) and my VM just acts like a router as tcpdump on ens3 shows my upstream traffic leaving it with srcIP=10.100.0.x, hence untranslated. When adding the nat entry in question I get no errors of any kind from ufw, so no idea why it's not added. I do have the route to 10.100.0.x/24, so all users can reach the UFW VM.

Comment: ```root@server:/etc/ufw# cat before.rules | grep MASQUERADE
*nat :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
root@server:/etc/ufw#
root@server:/etc/ufw# ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
root@server:/etc/ufw#
root@server:/etc/ufw# ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
root@server:/etc/ufw#```

Comment: ```root@server:/etc/ufw# iptables -t nat -L -v
...
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 670 packets, 41488 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
root@server:/etc/ufw#```

Comment: Update: just tried adding "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE" directly and now the entry is there and NAT is working fine, so I'll use it as a workaround. Meanwhile it'd be great to know what prevents ufw from adding the one in before.rules.

Comment: @dandreye You should edit the question with information. No one can know what you understand as prerequisite.

Comment: good point - just got it amended, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @dandreye I have edited the answer with more details

Comment: thank you. I had followed all those steps earlier and got no errors at any point but the NAT entry still never made it into that iptables table for some reason, so I ended up putting it into /etc/rc.local as I don't have time to troubleshoot UFW any further.